# 3rd party (employer's) app on android phone - what is the risk for an employee?

Tags: privacy, android

An employer (someone's employer) issued an **android** app and requests that all of the employees install it. During installation the app requests access to all of the phone's resources and it wouldn't work if the access is declined.

The official purpose of the app is sending some internal requests concerning work-related stuff. But, who knows, maybe an employer has some additional goals.

What is the risk for employees when installing such an app on a personal phone? What an employer might see on an employee's phone? Could it see the employee's location? What files or personal data can it get access to?

What can an employee do to restrict the employer's access?

The question is not about using a separate phone. It is about safely using the app on the employee's main personal phone.

Comment: Install on an emulator, or buy a cheap phone just for that.

Comment: By your own description, it has access to all the phones resources, which by definition would include location, files, etc.

Comment: @ThoriumBR I personally do not know what emulators are, and suppose that regular users don't know it either. Buying a cheap phone is not an option as the employee is expected to use the same phone number.

Comment: @schroeder all files or just some files? are there some folders that apps do not have access to? It would be really interesting to know some specifics.

Comment: What permissions mean on an Android phone is more of a question for Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Based on your response to the answers, I'm not really sure what you are looking for.  You ask, "What is the risk" and you have the answer (in fact, the app itself answers this for you) - the employer will be able to track everything you do and view all your files.  "What can I do to restrict this access" is questionably on topic.  It's far too broad, especially since you aren't specific about your concerns.

Comment: Most likely there *isn't* anything that can be done, at least without very technical solutions (rooting the phone, which you don't want to do), opsec solutions (use a different phone, which you also don't want to do), or simply refusing (which you also don't want to do).  So... really not sure how to help you here...

Comment: @ConorMancone People use phones and install apps, lots of apps, banking apps for example, password managers, etc. It is a common practice to install lots of apps. Everybody installs them. So I suppose the situation is not that bad. Maybe apps do not read each others' data, or maybe there are certain folders from which they can read. Maybe the operating system restricts some things. So I am hoping to get an answer from someone who knows Android operating system well.

Comment: @MindYB you've just described a vastly different scenario from your question. Was your post a strawman?

Comment: @schroeder sorry, I didn't understand, what is a different scenario? I just want to understand how android apps work. They are becoming more and more common. Everyone expects you install their app and if you don't, they decline the service. And employer is one case, which is very common. Banks and insurance companies also expect you to install apps and they may make it extremely inconvenient for you not to install it. This is where the world is moving right now. I am genuinely concerned.

Comment: Ok, you have posted a strawman. You have invented a scenario with very specific details  and asked how to handle ***those details***. But all you want to know is how Android permissions work. It would have been a lot better, and easier, to explain your true context instead of creating an arbitrary and unrealistic scenario.

Comment: @schoeder You always close my questions or suspect me of something evil. I am seriously beginning to feel annoyed. I didn't intend to do anything like that. I've just answered the comments after getting some really simplistic answers. While from my question it was clear from the beginning that I asked about installing an app on the same phone. Could you please stop suspecting me of things? If I'm new to the site or to the topic, it doesn't mean that I post strawmans or whatever.

Comment: I'm not closing your questions or suspecting you of anything evil. You have posted very confusing questions that evolve in the comments. The scenario you posted in your question is not a real scenario, right? You invented the details and the situation, right? And you did this so that you could better understand what is *really* happening. That's called a "strawman". I'm asking you to not do that, but to simply ask what you want to ask without arbitrary details. It's the details that cause the confusion.

Comment: @schroeder This is a real scenario. Why would you even think that it is not real? It is a real scenario. Should I repeat it again?

Comment: Then why are you bringing up banks, password managers, and other scenarios? Those don't apply to the details in your question. They don't ask for "all resources" and you can choose not to install them. To bring up all these other things in response to our handling of ***this*** scenario doesn't help. They are not equivalent.

Comment: @schroeder There are cases when it is impossible not to install a banking app that I know of. If you do not know of them, it doesn't mean that these situations do not exist. THis is definitely not a reason to suspect me of lying. I just tried to clarify my point, that people use 3rd party apps on their phones even when it's a banking app that can access personal data to gather information on a client. A strategy of one app per one phone is completely unrealistic.

Comment: Bank apps do not request "all the phone's resources". This is the point that we are all making. That the example app in your post asks for "all the phone's resources" is what makes this situation unique and very, very different from a bank app. The situations are not equivalent. So, I'll ask again: is the app in the scenario asking for "all the phone's resources" or is that an exaggeration or your interpretation? Do you believe that bank apps and password managers ask for "all the phone's resources"?

Comment: @schroeder Look, if we continue this thread this way, I might end up giving away the details that I really do not want to post here. Could you just stop questioning me and let those people who know something answer the question.

Comment: Does the app ask to be set as a device admin app?

Comment: I'm asking you to confirm a detail that you have already disclosed. How can that be exposing more info than you already have?

Comment: @schroeder what can I do if you just don't understand what I say. What is not clear from what I say? Ok, I think I will not post in this community again.

Comment: When you feel able, please edit your question with the details I have asked for. Insulting people, berating people, and being uncooperative when we are trying to help means that maybe this isn't the place for you.

Comment: Hey, @schroeder, do you have an email, or is there a way to PM you? I feel like we've started on a wrong foot, and I would like to know you better. If you don't want to share your email here you can drop me an email at the address that I've used for registration.

Comment: @MindYB contact outside of StackExchange in side-channels is discouraged. We do have chat rooms, but I cannot jump into one tonight. I don't think you need to understand me, the person, better. My focus is entirely on your words. I'm trying to address what you are saying and trying to understand your context so that an answer can be formed. What tends to happen is that your comments shift the context of your questions, so then I'm trying to get to a foundational context.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no options but to install and assign all permissions, then you have few options.

The risks are everything you've suggested and more, given your scenario. Such an app would have access to everything your phone does.

You could use the resources on your phone to segregate the app to a walled-off section of the phone. Not all phones have this. Samsung had Knox that allowed someone to split their phone in 2: one side for personal, and the other for work. This was not popular and didn't last long.

If you have rooted your phone, you can install walled-off areas, but then the rooting process introduces its own vulnerabilities and is not for the average user.

There's a reason why Android is really explicit to users when apps ask for permissions; they have a very real impact on the user.

Comment: The thing is that in case you decline permissions, the apps do not work. So in most cases it is equivalent to not installing the app.

Comment: My answer never suggests declining permissions. I'm saying that there is a reason why Android is explicit: that the permissions have a very real impact.

Comment: Keep in mind, even an app that has lots of privileges generally cannot (without further manual settings enabled): read data from other apps or spy on you using them, keylog you, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> What can an employee do to restrict the employer's access?

If you want to run the app on the same device, you would essentially have to sandbox the app to isolate it from the rest of the device and your personal data.

A quick google search for it turns up [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.island&hl=en_US) but it appears to be under development and may be unstable. [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.typeblog.shelter&hl=en_US) is an opensource alternative.

Comment: Isn't an app that you're suggesting to use is an app itself? So if each app is dangerous to the phone's data, how an app can be a solution?

Comment: @MindYB your comment makes no sense. What do you want to protect yourself from? All apps or the employer's app?

Comment: @MindYB You're right. You would simply be transferring trust from your employers app to the sandbox app. But the app claims not to collect personal data (make sure you read its privacy policy before using it to determine the true scope of the claim) so you may have some legal protection in this case.

Comment: That app also has a much smaller set of permissions than the "all resources" in the OP.

Comment: Well I suppose in order to do it, an Island app creates a separate file system and moves all of the data into it. So in this case all of your data is compromised. Doesn't look good at all. And I don't suppose it's possible to go to court with the owners in Zhejiang, China, unless the app is used by local citizens.

Comment: @MindYB Who said it moves all your data into it?

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, the risk is that the company will be able to track your activity, in detail, on your phone.  There is not a solution built into the Android ecosystem, so the only options are very technical ones (rooting the phone and creating custom "firewalls" in it).  However, you aren't interested in this sort of solution, so there are only a few options:

1. Install the app and accept the fact that the employer may be able to track everything that happens on the personal device
2. Refuse to install the app and hope you don't get fired (assuming the company can legally do so)
3. Lie and say you don't own an android phone (I personally don't recommend this one)
4. Find a new job.

There is no magic bullet here.

Comment: So you suppose if I install a banking app, for example, it can also watch me in all possible ways? Or an insurance app can watch me fully and raise my insurance price for example? Why do people use apps in this case and not just throw away android phones?

Comment: @MindYB to pick one of your examples: if your insurance app asks for location information all the time then yes, it could absolutely use GPS to track your driving habits and possibly raise your rates as a result of what it records (laws permitting).  Android does have some limits built in (such as reading another app's data), but there is plenty of very sensitive data that could be extracted just the same, especially if you grant an app all permissions.

Comment: I look over the permissions of every app very carefully, and I have refused to install many apps I was interested in because they asked for far too many permissions.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/28/business/media/alphonso-app-tracking.html